# Customers who upgraded from which mobile to which in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the table

[image: customer]

Cname = customer name,

MobileSl = Mobile serial number e.g customer's 1st mobile, 2nd mobile and so on,

Mname = Mobile name

Need a query in sql server to retrieve customer's latest mobile and also the mobile from which he upgraded.
    e.g. Girish has upgraded from nokia to micromax.

Comment: Use a subquery to get max(MobileSl) together with the other columns and join ths subquery back to your table with subqry.Cname=[the table].Cname AND subqry.MobileSl = [the table].MobileSl + 1. Depending on the SQL Server version I'd rather use a cte and OUTER APPLY, but unfortunately there's no information about the version you use. Therefore, I've described the "old-fashioned" way that'll work with any version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH recentPhone as (
SELECT Cname, MAX(MobileSI) as recentSI
from RECORDS
GROUP BY Cname
)
SELECT
CASE WHEN earlier.Mname is null THEN
RECORDS.Cname + ' has just got their first mobile, a ' + RECORDS.Mname
ELSE
RECORDS.Cname + ' has upgraded from a ' + RECORDS.Mname + ' to a ' + earlier.Mname
END as results
FROM
RECORDS
INNER JOIN recentPhone ON RECORDS.Cname = recentPhone.Cname AND RECORDS.MobileSI = recentPhone.recentSI
LEFT JOIN RECORDS AS earlier ON RECORDS.Cname = earlier.Cname AND (RECORDS.MobileSI - 1) = earlier.MobileSI
```

Query assumes your table name is RECORDS, please replace RECORDS with actual table name for this to work.  This query finds the max MobileSI associated with a customer name(you should really use Customer IDs because name repetition is not the best unique identifier...).  It then constrains RECORDS to return rows associated with that max ID.  Then there is a left join to another instance of RECORDS to check if there is an earlier phone.  There is a CASE statement in the main query to deal with a customer who has only purchased one phone thus far.

Have fun and be safe out there!